# Почему Не работает реклама с вознаграждением?

Tags: unity3d, admob, unity3d-android

использую Google Mobile Ads. Создал 3 баннера. Обычный, Межстраничный и с Вознаграждением.
Первые два работают,а вот третий почему-то отказывается. Сделал всё как в инструкции.
**Вот код**:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
.....
    void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize("ca-app-pub-00000000000000~9000000000");
        this.rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;
        AdRequest requestReward = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(requestReward, reward_video);
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += OnAdLoaded;
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded;
    }

    private void OnAdLoaded(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoLoaded(object sender, Reward args)
    {
          // Добавляем очки за просмотр
          Scores += 20;
    }

        public void AdvReward()
    {
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdLoaded += OnAdLoaded;
        rewardBasedVideo.Show();
    }
```

Всё это хочу, чтобы показывалось по кнопке. Вешаю на кнопку AdvReward() и в итоге ничего не происходит вообще.
Ни при запуске игры, ни при нажатии на кнопку. Логи в самом Unity пишут, что баннер открывается и показывается (при загрузке - загружается, при нажатии на кнопку - показывается).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по итогу, на телефоне, ничего не происходит.
В AdMob группы медиаций нет, просто создано объявление с вознаграждением.

**Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Спасибо!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы убедиться, что с вашей интеграцией adMob все в порядке попробуйте сдедующие пункты:

- Тестируйте на устройстве. В редакторе Unity реклама скорее всего показываться не будет
- Чтобы проверить, что с вашим кодом все в порядке попробуйте проверить рекламу на [тестовых id](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/test-ads). В документации написаны тестовые id рекламы, которые точно работают и показывают рекламу. Вам нужно собрать приложение с тестовым рекламным id, запустить получить в логах тестовый идентификатор устройства и пересобрать приложение немного изменив инициализацию рекламы:

  ```
  AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("testDeviceId").Build();
  ```

  вставив id устройства, который вы получите в логах вместо "testDeviceId". Если при следующем запуске реклама покажется без проблем, значит ваш код работает корректно и дело в id rewarded video.
- Если вашего приложения еще нет в магазине, и вы проверили, что ваш код работает корректно (пункт выше), то возможен еще один вариант - [как в случае из официально группы admob](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/game-engines/l4iC2mZSRkc). А именно, проверено, что с интеграцией все нормально, и агент поддержки выяснил, что приложение не выложено в магазин. При этом он пишет:

> If your application is not published to the App Store, please note that it is expected that you will have lower fill rates

Что можно интерпретировать как, с интеграцией все нормально, с кампанией рекламы все нормально, но fill rate приложения низкий (нет установок) и по этому admob не может найти подходящий ролик для показа. При выкладке в стор данная проблема решится.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию, видимо проблема действительно в последнем пункте. Будем выкладываться тогда и по мере скачек уже работать. Потому что изначально код работал без проблем) Спасибо.